# Angular JS conversion to Angular with ngFor interpolation

Tags: angular, navigation, angularjs-ng-repeat, href, ngfor

I am working on converting an Angular JS application into Angular, and I'm stuck on one spot.  I have an old ng-repeat loop with interpolation in the html that worked in JS but no longer. It is meant to navigate on page to sections tagged with ids.

OLD

```
    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="tag in vm.tags">
            <a href="#{{tag.id}}" ng-click="vm.highlightSection(tag.id)">{{tag.display}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

NEW

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let tag of (noteItem$ | async)?.tags">
          <a (click)="vm.highlightSection(tag.id)">{{tag.display}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The interpolation is grabbing tag.display just fine.  But the vm.highlightSection(tag.id) is not navigating within the page to the requested tag id.  What can I do to get the navigation link to reference my tag id and navigate there?

Thanks

Comment: where is `vm` declared? why you don´t call a method directly like "`highlightSection`" instead

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation is handled here: `<a href="#{{tag.id}}"` when you want to navigate using your router it would be something like this: `<a [routerLink]="['#', tag.id] ... />"`

Find more information here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: I added <a href="#{{tag.id}}" ... /> and it's grabbing the interpolation fine, but on click, it routes me to my base url www.examplesite.com/#exampleTag instead of navigating to the tag on the page